# There exist $y \in K$ and $b \in E \setminus F$ such that $\min(y,E)(X) = X^3-b$ in a concrete fields $F \leq E \leq K$

Tags: field-theory, extension-field

Let $F \leq E \leq K$ be a finite extension of fields, with $[K : F] = 6$ and $[E : F] = 2$ (so $[K : E] = 3$), such that $K / E$ is normal and $E = F(x)$, being $x \in E$ a root of $X^2 + X + 1$. I have to show that there exist $y \in K$ and $b \in E \setminus F$ such that $\min(y , E)(X) = X^3 - b$ (I can use also that the characteristic of $F$ is neither $2$ nor $3$ if I needed). My attempt is the next: the extension $K / F$ is finite and I have shown that it is separable too, so using the primitive element theorem, there exists $y \in K$ such that $K = E(y)$. Generally, using that $E = F(x)$, we have that there exist ${\alpha}_i , {\beta}_i \in F$ ($i \in \{0 , 1 , 2\}$) such that
$$
\min(y , E)(X) = X^3 + ({\alpha}_2 + {\beta}_2 x) X^2 + ({\alpha}_1 + {\beta}_1 x) X + {\alpha}_0 + {\beta}_0 x
$$
as $3 = [K : E] = \deg \min(y , E)$ and the elements of $E$ are like $\alpha + \beta x$, with $\alpha , \beta \in F$. We have that $K / E$ is a Galois extension too, as it is normal, but it is also separable (as $K / F$ is separable). How can I use it? In fact, $E / F$ is a Galois extension too, because it is normal (as each any cuadratic extension is normal) and it is separable (as $K / F$ is separable). I know how I can use neither this nor that $x$ is a primitive cubic root of unity to conclude that $\min(y , E)(X) = X^3 - b$, with $b \in E \setminus F$. Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Unfortunately, I am not entirely sure what you are asking. Please allow me to clarify. We have a chain of field extensions $F \leq E \leq K$ such that $[K : F] = 6$ and $[E : F] = 2.$ We are also given that $K$ is a normal extension of $E$ and that $E = F(\zeta),$ where $\zeta$ is a primitive cube root of unity since it is a root of the polynomial $x^2 + x + 1$ over $F.$ We need to prove that there exist $\alpha \in K$ and $\beta \in E - F$ such that the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ over $E$ is $x^3 - \beta.$ Correct?

Comment: By the way, what notion of "normal" are you using? Certain texts define a normal extension as a separable splitting field of some polynomial over a field. Other texts (and Wikipedia) define it as the property of a field such that any polynomial with a root in that field splits in that field.

Comment: Exactly, it is the problem. And you can suppose also that the characteristic of $F$ (or $E$ or $K$) is neither $2$ nor $3$, but I am not sure if we need this. On the other hand, my definition of normal extension of fields is the next: an algebraic extension of fields $L / L_0$ is normal if there exists a family of polynomials $\mathcal{F}$ in $F[X]$ such that $L$ is splitting field for $\mathcal{F}$ over $F$. It is equivalent to this statement: $L / L_0$ is normal if $L$ is the splitting field for $\{\min(z,L_0):z \in S\}$ over $L_0$, supposing that $L = L_0(S)$.

Comment: We want to show that $K$ contains a cube root of a primitive cube root of unity, i.e., that $K$ contains a primitive ninth root of unity.

Comment: It seems plausible that $K$ contains a primitive ninth root of unity. Given that $F = \mathbb{Q},$ we have that $\Phi_9(x) = x^6 + x^3 + 1$ is an irreducible (3-Eisenstein) polynomial, hence the degrees of $K$ and $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_9)$ match.

Comment: But $F$ may not be $\mathbb{Q}$. In fact, the characteristic of $F$ may not be $0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one of the elementary lemmas leading to Kummer theory.

You know that $K/E$ is Galois with Galois group cyclic of order three. If $\sigma$ is a generator of the Galois group, and $\omega\in E$ is a zero of $x^2+x+1$, then Artin's Lemma on *independence of characters* gives that there exists an element $z\in E$ such that
$$x:=z+\omega\sigma(z)+\omega^2\sigma(z)\neq0.$$
Attack:

1. Show that $\sigma(x)=\omega^{-1}x$. Conclude that $x\notin E$.
2. Show that $\sigma(x^3)=x^3$. Conclude that $x^3\in E$.

Comment: Using that $K / E$ is a Galois extension with Galois group cyclic of order three and using that $E$ contains a cube root primitive of unity, I have obtained directly that there exists $z \in K$ such that $\min(z , E)(X) = X^3 - a$. After this, we would have to see that we can replace $z$ by $y \in K$ and $a$ by $b \in E \setminus F$ such that $\min(y , E)(X) = X^3 - b$. And here it is solved: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2880160/there-exist-y-in-k-and-b-in-e-setminus-f-such-that-miny-e-x3-b. Thank you very much by your help. I am very grateful